# Pockels Cell reverse propagation

Tags: optics, laser, polarization, non-linear-optics

Pockels Cells are called "voltage controlled waveplates", since the voltage changes the birefringence of the material, leading to the same birefringence induced change of total polarisation plane than in wave plates.

However, it is known that waveplates, unlike Faraday Rotators, are reciprocal, meaning if you send a beam of light through a waveplate, let it reflect somewhere and let it pass through the plate once more, the total effect is zero.

However, in a Pockels Cell, this seems not to be the case, as one lecture slide to Q-switching of lasers via Pockels cells imply:
[image]

On the left hand side, the (I assume) vertical polarized light goes through the activated cell, it gets circularly polarized, gets reflected, and passes through the cell once more, leading to horizontal polarized light.
This is similiar to a Faraday rotator, and not to a waveplate.

Am I right of is there something wrong with my observations?

Best regards

Comment: "However, it is known that waveplates, unlike Faraday Rotators, are reciprocal, meaning if you send a beam of light through a waveplate, let it reflect somewhere and let it pass through the plate once more, the total effect is zero" this is not true for a generic waveplate but only for a half-waveplate. If you have a quarter waveplate acting twice on the component of an electric field, the total shift after two passages will be half of a period (so it is acting as half-waveplate with the same axis).

Answer (score 1):

On the slide you posted the Pockels cell acts as a controlled quarter-wave plate, so if the light passes through it twice the total effect is identical to half-wave plate. This way the polarisation is rotated by $90^{\circ}$ and the polariser blocks the light.

The main (operational) difference between the Faraday rotator and half-wave plate is that the rotation direction in Faraday rotator depends on the propagation direction (with respect to the magnetic field applied to obtain the Faraday effect). Therefore using Faraday rotator and two polarisers you can build the optical isolator, which you can't do using wave plates. The reason is that if the light passes through half-wave plate (without any additional polarisation changes) the total effect is analogous to full-wave plate, so there is no change in polarisation.

Comment: The first part is my problem. If you send light through a quarter wave plate, let it come back and run through it a second time, the effects of both should cancel each other out, right? So I don't see why a Pockels cell should work differently.

Comment: No. The wave plate is just a phase shifter - it shifts phase between the ordinary and extraordinary ray. The phase shift of the half-wave plate (HWP) is equal $\phi_{HWP}=\pi$, when for quarter-wave plate (QWP) the shift is just $\phi_{QWP}=\pi/2$. So if you decompose the polarisation in the linear polarisation basis aligned to the optical axis of the plate (ordinary and extraordinary ray) you will find that  if the light passes twice (even in opposite direction) through the wave plate the shift is just equal $2\phi_{HWP}=2\pi$ for HWP and $2\phi_{QWP}=\pi/2=\phi_{HWP}$ for QWP.

Comment: Ok. 
So where is the difference then to a Faraday Rotator in the same setup?
See my comment to the other answer:
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_isolator#The_Faraday_rotator

"Optical isolators are different from 1/4 wave plate based isolators because the Faraday rotator provides non-reciprocal rotation while maintaining linear polarization." So the only difference is that in a Faraday rotator, the light stays linearly polarized the whole time, even between both passes?

Comment: One of the main point of the Pockels cell compared to a standard quarter waveplate/optical isolator is that it can be "switched" on and off rapidly (also it is possible to chose an arbitrary phase delay between 0 and the maximum delay, whereas for a standard waveplate you're stuck with a fixed delay).

Answer (score 1):

Any quarter-wave plate would act the same way as the Poeckels cell in this situation, and you can purchase passive optical isolators that work on the same principle. The nice thing about the Poeckels cell is the ability to rapidly turn the rotation on and off.

A quarter-wave plate has a fast axis and a slow axis. If light enters the quarter-wave plate with linear polarization, so that the components along the fast and slow axes are in phase, it will leave with the component along the fast axis advanced by a quarter-period, which is one handedness of circular polarization.

When the light is reflected, the advanced component of the linear polarization is still advanced. (This means that reflection reverses the circular polarization of the light, which is what's needed to conserve the light's angular momentum.) So when the reflected light re-enters the quarter-wave plate, the component along the fast axis gets advanced *again*. Now the fast component is a half-period ahead of the slow: linear polarization again, but rotated compared to how it entered.

Comment: So where is the difference then between a wave plate/pockels cell and a faraday rotator?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_isolator#The_Faraday_rotator

 "Optical isolators are different from 1/4 wave plate based isolators because the Faraday rotator provides non-reciprocal rotation while maintaining linear polarization."

So the only difference is that in a Faraday rotator, the light stays linearly polarized the whole time, even between both passes?

Comment: In the Faraday effect, the speed difference is between the two circular polarizations of light, while in a quarter-wave plate the difference is between two linear polarizations.

Comment: but for practical purposes like in the slide, they are the same`?

Comment: I'm not sure about the practical considerations that would lead to choosing one over the other. Might warrant a follow-up question.